# Docker containers- running new java8 code on old java6 version

Tags: ubuntu, docker, spring-boot, java-8, dockerfile

I have a new java8 web application(spring boot) that needs to run on a one of the old environment application boxes which has java 6.

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

i am amateur in docker's usage, but heard that you run the app inside the Docker container and give the config you want.In this case i want to run java8 on already installed java6.

please suggest is it possible? if so provide some references to start.

Answer (score 2):

The java6 installed on your old environment doesn't matter.

If you can install docker on that environment, then you can create a docker image which contains java8, put your application in it and launch it on the server.

You can try it by launching

```
docker run -ti --rm livingobjects/jre8:8u71 java -version
```

on your "old" server, it will give you an output like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed guide available at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: yes, but wondering whether it will work on already installed old java environments (prior java8) or it need extra set up.

Comment: While the page says you need Java 8, I think that's only if you want to compile your app and automate the building process on that machine. If you can compile your app somewhere else, and use `docker build` directly, it should be fine.